# Magento2: After installing elastic search ik, but not showing the right search result

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Magento2: After installing elastic search ik, but not showing the right search result.

so it containes two analyzer that ik_max_word and ik_smart from ik. How can I config or change in magento?

Any suggestions?